# OpenTSDB Web interface showing nothing other than header and footer

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, logging, hbase, opentsdb

NOTE: I moved the question from stackoverflow to serverfault as this question didn't attract attention.

I have a temporary OpenTSDB and hbase hosted on a aws micro server. `http://54.72.180.169:4242/`

I have checked HBase and 2 tables are created by tsdb successfully without LZO compression.

I can successfully start the TSDB using the following command.

```
./build/tsdb tsd --port=4242 --staticroot=build/staticroot --cachedir=/tmp/tsd
```

But when I go to my web interface, I can see nothing but Open TSDB header and footer.

I get some warnings in my console whenever I refresh the page.

```
2014-04-10 09:05:23,972 WARN  [New I/O worker #1] HttpQuery: [id: 0xd0cdd077, /83.217.124.75:46401 => /172.31.19.35:4242] File not found: build/staticroot/queryui.nocache.js (No such file or directory)
2014-04-10 09:05:23,973 WARN  [New I/O worker #1] HttpQuery: [id: 0xd0cdd077, /83.217.124.75:46401 => /172.31.19.35:4242] Not Found: /s/queryui.nocache.js
```

Please help me with this.

Update: You can also have a look at my Hbase Installation information at

```
http://54.72.180.169:60010/
```

Many thanks,

Karthik

Comment: Did you fix this ? The tsdb install has a static content directory that it cannot find. (though I guess you probably figured it out already....)

Comment: Sorry Nicholas, I stopped using TSDB after finding that there is very little community support....

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Hopefully, if you ever revisit, you'll find things improved....